# Automate word with applescript

Tags: applescript

I am new to Applescript.  I want to automate word but don’t know how. Your help will be deeply appreciated. I have a word document which is a parent letter.  I have an excel document with two columns that contain the parent’s name and price for school bus fee. What I want to do are:

Replace the parent name in word document using the data in column A of the excel file

Replace the bus fee in the word document using the data in column B of the excel file

Generate a word document

Print it via the default printer on my Mac.

Repeat the steps above until the end of the excel

I am not sure if I’ve explained clearly what I want.   If I have 30 rows of data in excel, I will get 30 word documents printed out after running the script.

Thanks again,
Yu SUN from China

Comment: You should do this using Word's merge feature... not using AppleScript. Search for microsoft word's merge functionality for a tutorial. It's not difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Michael, I think it would be much easier to use the form letter and mail merge capabilities built into Microsoft Office. You may want to do some searching on your own, but here's an example tutorial from Microsoft for Office 2011:

http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/7/F/A7F9018D-3B23-4EDA-A554-A128C74C366C/Word%20tutorial%20-%20Use%20Mail%20Merge%20to%20create%20a%20form%20letter.pdf

If you search help for "mail merge" in Office 2016 you'll get some detailed steps, too.